# Finding if a value exists in a cell containing comma separated text

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column which contains a comma-separated list of numbers:
"3, 5, 11"

I need like to have a continuous bunch of cells, each with the value true or false based on whether the corresponding cell value exists in the CSV string.
IE cell 1 would check for "1" in the string, cell 2 for "2" in the string etc.

`SEARCH()` isn't a good solution, because searching for "1" would yield true even if only the value 11 exists (and not 1).

So in a sense, it's about doing a SPLIT, then searching the result of that function.

What would be the formula for that in one of those cells?

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Welcome! Yes, SPLIT() combined with MATCH() will do the trick: `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(<tested value - your 1 or 2 or 11>,SPLIT(<cell for testing>, ", " , 1,1),0)),FALSE(),TRUE())`

Comment: Thanks @JohnSUN ! That solved my issue.  If you were to post it as an answer I'd mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**SPLIT()**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) combined with [**MATCH()**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en) will do the trick:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(<tested value>,SPLIT(<cell for testing>, ", " , 1,1),0)),FALSE(),TRUE())
```